# Jenkins Docker container with root permissions?

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, docker-machine

I want to build a jenkins docker container with root permissions so that i can us apt-get feature to install gradle.

I am using this command to run jenkins on 8080 port but i also want to add gradle as enviornment variable :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

or what dockerfile i need to create and what to write in it so that jenkins also start running at 8080

Comment: i was trying a wrong command which just created a directory with name gradle in container running jenkins. but then i able to enter as root and installed gradle. i will post answer to my question now. Thanks anyway  :) @StephenKing

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I am now able to login into my docker container as root and apt-get can be used to install gradle or anything manually into the container.

Command i used to enter as root in container :

```
docker exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash
```

Comment: Good that you solved the problem. For the long term, you should put these commands into a `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Will keep that in mind and use Dockerfile instead of running commands directly

Answer (score 0):

Building an image that sets `USER` to `root` will make all interactive logins use `root`.

Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root
```

Then (setting *your* container ID):

```
docker exec -it jenkins_jenkins_1 bash
root@9e8f16419754:/$
```

Comment: Building an image that sets USER to root will make all interactive logins use root
Is this risk to make default user in Jenkins image root?

Answer (score 0):

docker run --user=root -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).